# Add to array only within scope of function

Tags: bash, array, function

I'm writing a function that will make a REST API calls which could be either `GET`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, `POST`, etc.

**I would like to feed this method to the function as a parameter and add it to the options array for that single function call.  Is this possible?**

Currently I am solving this by creating a separate `local` array but would prefer to only use the single `options` array.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

options=(
    --user me:some-token
    -H "Accept: application/json"
)

some_func () {
    local urn=$1
    shift
    local func_opts=("${options[@]}" "$@")
    printf '%s\n' "${func_opts[@]}"
}

# This should return all options including -X GET
some_func /test -X GET

# This should return only the original options
printf '%s\n' "${options[@]}"
```

---

I could also use a temporary array to store the contents of `options`, add the new options, and then reset it before the function ends, but I don't think that is a particularly clean method either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to explicitly use a subshell for the function, then override its local copy of the array, knowing that once the subshell exits, the original variable is unchanged:

```
# a subshell in () instead of the common {}, in order to munge a local copy of "options"
some_func () (
    local urn=$1
    shift
    options+=("$@")
    printf '%s\n' "${options[@]}"
)
```

Answer (score 5):

With bash 5.0 and above, you can use the `localvar_inherit` option which causes `local` to behave like in ash-based shells, that is where `local var` makes the variable local without changing its value or attributes:

```
shopt -s localvar_inherit
options=(
  --user me:some-token
  -H "Accept: application/json"
)
some_func () {
  local urn=$1
  shift
  local options # make it local, does not change the type nor value
  options+=("$@")
  printf '%s\n' "${options[@]}"
}

some_func /test -X GET
```

With any version, you can also do:

```
some_func () {
  local urn=$1
  shift
  eval "$(typeset -p options)" # make a local copy of the outer scope's variable
  options+=("$@")
  printf '%s\n' "${options[@]}"
}
```