# Appending to local array

Tags: bash, array

Have defined an array local to a function

```
isufx+=( -name "*$fltyp" -o )
```

When I call the function again, the previous values in array `isufx` are not being cleared and the array unset.  Instead the values of tho second function call are being appended to those mad in the first call.

How can the array `isufx` be refreshed when calling it again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/499553/237982

Comment: The focus seems to be different.

Comment: If that is true than you need to clarify your question because as I read it it is pretty much exactly the same.

Comment: What is there inside the function? Is `isufx` declared as `local` there? Initialized by a regular assignment? By default, shell variables are global, and if all you do to one, is to append more elements, well, then it indeed never clears.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could create your function in a subshell instead of using the traditional curly brackets.

```
my_func () (
  local isufx+=( -name "*$fltyp" -o )
  do-the-things
)
```

Comment: Have figured out that I was transferring the contents of `isufx` to another array which was not defined as local.  Thusly, the problem emerged.

Comment: I don't see how the subshell is necessary if the variable is made `local`... E.g. `foo() { local foo+=bar; echo $foo; }` prints `bar` just once, regardless of how many times it was called before. (Also, I have this awkward feeling that doing the assignment right in the `local` was problematic in some cases, but I can't remember why.)